# SoftKeyboard Hide issue in Fragment

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

**TASK :**  Have to hide Soft_Keyboard when user comes back from Recent to Application. (Taking about coming back to Fragment from Recent), There should no Soft_Keyboard in open mode.

**ISSUE** : Soft_keyboard remains open when i am coming back from recent mode.

**EFFORTS :**  To hide soft_keyboard I have done below lines of Code in onStart(), onResume(), onCreate() and also in my custom method init() inside Fragment.

**CODE :** as below :

1. CALL : `CommonUtil.hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());`
2. Lines :

   ```
    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context context) {
           try {
               InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   View focusedView = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();
                   //If no view is focused, an NPE will be thrown
                   if (focusedView != null) {
                       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
   ```

.. I have tried above code in [enter code] but, it still looks like this: hope you can understood.

Anyway,

What might be the solution ? 
Thanks.

NOTE : I don't wanna to use **ADJUST_PAN**. ;)

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting same issue when try to close the soft-keyboard from `Fragment` but I solved with passing the view which is having the focus and below code works fine for me.

```
  public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are passing as a view in argument.. hidekeyboard(?);

Comment: your current focusing view

Comment: i tried all the controls(view) of layout. no success

Answer (score 0):

When the fragment is no longer visible, the EditText View still retains the focus so the keyboard remains visible.
However;  When the fragment transitions from visible to no longer visible execution can be intercepted as follows:

...

```
override fun onStop() {
// Fragment transitions from visible to not visible
super.onStop()
hideSoftKeyboard()}
    
fun hideSoftKeyboard(){
myEditTextView1.clearFocus()
myEditTextView2.clearFocus()
//etc
}
```

...

If you cannot be sure which Edit textview has the focus you must clearFocus() on all views as you move from one fragment to another.
This worked for me like a charm....